# React-native .map undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, react-native

here my code :

```
componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm)
        getFilmDetailFromApi(this.props.navigation.state.params.idFilm).then(data => {
            this.setState({
                film: data,
                isLoading: false,
            })
        })
    }

_displayFilm() {
        if(this.state != '') {
            const { film } = this.state
            return (
                <ScrollView>
                    <Image>

                    </Image>
                    <View style={styles.overview_container}>
                        <Text style={styles.overview_title}>{film.title}</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.overview_description}>{film.overview}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.informations_container}>
                        <Text>Sorti le {film.release_date}</Text>
                        <Text>Note : {film.vote_average}</Text>
                        <Text>Nombre de votes : {film.vote_count}</Text>
                        <Text>Budget : {numeral(film.budget).format('0,0[.]00 $')}</Text>
                        <Text>Genre(s) : {film.genres.map((item) => {
                            console.log(item)
                        })}</Text>
                        <Text></Text>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            )
        }
    }
```

Console.log of film.genres :

```
Array [
  Object {
    "id": 12,
    "name": "Aventure",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 14,
    "name": "Fantastique",
  },
  Object {
    "id": 10751,
    "name": "Familial",
  },
]
```

I have this error :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'film.genres.map')

All is okay but not the Genre(s), anyone have an idea of why the .map don't works correctly with my array of objects ? Thank's.

Comment: Where did you write Console.log of film.genres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going over steps:

1.First, add an initial state value inside your class component

```
  state = {
    film: null,
    isLoading: false,
  };
```

2.Second you can trigger the `isLoading` boolean to true inside your componentDidMount before doing the API call

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    getFilmDetailFromApi(navigation.state.params.idFilm).then((data) => {
      this.setState({ film: data, isLoading: false });
    });
  }
```

3.Now we can use this `isLoading` prop to render a spinner or any loading UI before rendering the films since they're not yet available to access.

```
_displayFilm() {
    const { film, isLoading } = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
      return <View>Loading films...</View>;
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <Image></Image>
        <View style={styles.overview_container}>
          <Text style={styles.overview_title}>{film.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.overview_description}>{film.overview}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.informations_container}>
          <Text>Sorti le {film.release_date}</Text>
          <Text>Note : {film.vote_average}</Text>
          <Text>Nombre de votes : {film.vote_count}</Text>
          <Text>Budget : {numeral(film.budget).format('0,0[.]00 $')}</Text>
          <Text>
            Genre(s) :{' '}
            {film.genres.map((item) => {
              console.log(item);
            })}
          </Text>
          <Text></Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Hope that works. Let me know if you got any questions!

Comment: Thank you ! Why we need to use ' {' '} ' before the .map ?

Comment: No problem! Sorry for that is just Prettier trying to improve the code a little more.

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
...
<Text>Genre(s) : {(film && film.genres) && film.genres.map((item) => {
   console.log(item)
})}</Text>
...
```

or

```
...
<Text>Genre(s) : {(film && film.genres) ? film.genres.map((item) => {
   console.log(item)
}) : null}</Text>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with your first solution, so what is this syntax ?

Comment: It takes some time to do setState so there are some milliseconds with no value in film. so film.genres could be undefined. Then you call map in undefined object then error occures. 